# Check if location is in route path

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an app where the user select a destination and mark the route to that destination in google map to get there. The situation is that now I have to show all places that are 1 km or less away from the route. Those places are set by a person manually.

For example, if the user choose from NY to California, a route of how to get there will be marked and all interesting places, saved by a person, will be shown in the map but those places that are more than 1 km away from the route cannot be displayed.

I dont know if that is even possible. Can you please guide me here?
Sorry for my english, not my natural lang.

Answer (score 0):

Across the US you will have places that have more interesting places than will fit on the map.  [Start Here and learn how to cluster markers](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/docs/reference.html)